# Concatenate a ColdFusion variable before it's read

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am not sure if this is possible. Can I concatenate two strings representing a variable name, and then read the variable value from that? For example:

```
<cfloop index="person" from="0" to="#numberAuthorized - 1#">
  //USING 'thePerson' DIDN'T WORK EITHER
  <cfset thePerson = 'authorized_name' & person>
  <cfquery name="qAddAuthorizedPeople" datasource="#thedb#" blockfactor="100">
    INSERT INTO people (requestid, fullname)
    VALUES ('#requestid#', '#authorized_name & 1#')
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The variables I need to read are `authorized_name0, authrozied_name1, etc.`. So I'm looping so I can increment an index an append it to the end of the variable name. Then insert into my database like that. Obviously, this isn't working. I also tried concatenating before and setting it to a variable (thePerson) and putting `#thePerson#` in the query, but that also didn't work. Any way I can do this?

Comment: This seems like an unconventional way of doing that, so maybe it's just not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Are you looping through a list of names you are getting from somewhere else in the app and wanting to insert those names into the db?

Comment: _"concatenate a coldfusion before it's read"_ - huh!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** I am not sure how you are passing these variables. But say they are in the `FORM` scope... FORM is a structure too. With any structure, you can access the keys dynamically using associative array notation. (Also, be sure to properly scope your variables.)

```
<cfloop from="0" to="#numberAuthorized - 1#" index="counter">
  <!--- extract value of authorized_name0, authorized_name1, ... --->
  <cfset variables.fullName = FORM["authorized_name"& counter]>

  <cfquery name="qAddAuthorizedPeople" datasource="#thedb#" blockfactor="100">
    INSERT INTO people (requestid, fullname)
    VALUES (
      <cfqueryparam value="#requestid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      , <cfqueryparam value="#variables.fullName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    )
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I'm not sure he's getting this via the FORM scope though. OP, could you clarify what form you are getting the information from? Either way you should also incorporate cfqueryparam like @Leigh has in his example.

Comment: @JamesRLamar - Yeah, I am not sure either. It is not clear from the code (Updated answer to reflect the open question)

Comment: Because of that weird method that creates a struct of the form inputs, the form object never gets passed. It does put the fields into the ARGUMENTS struct though, so your answer still works with arguments instead of form. Thanks!

Comment: If the variables were just ordinary variables then they would be in the VARIABLES scope and could be accessed through the VARIABLES struct in a manner similar to the FORM struct above.

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting your list of names from a query this how you would loop through and add them in an INSERT to the db:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#structCount(numberAuthorized)#" index="person">
    <cfquery name="qAddAuthorizedPeople" datasource="#thedb#" blockfactor="100">
    INSERT INTO people (requestid, fullname)
    VALUES ('#requestid#', '#numberAuthorized["authorized_name"][person]#')
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

In the above example "authorized_name" is assumed to be the name of the column the table or structure you are getting the names from. This could just as easily come from a struct of some kind.

I changed the to range to use structCount(numberAuthorized) if that is the name of the form struct coming in. If the form names have values appended to the end of each name like "authorized_name_0" and "authorized_name_1", it would be clearer in the code to set those variables before each insertion just so it is clear that is what you are doing. Example:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#structCount(numberAuthorized)#" index="person">
  <cfset counter = counter + 1>
  <cfset newFullname = numberAuthorized["authorized_name_" & counter]>
  <cfquery name="qAddAuthorizedPeople" datasource="#thedb#" blockfactor="100">
  INSERT INTO people (requestid, fullname)
  VALUES ('#requestid#', '#numberAuthorized["authorized_name"][person]#')
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

It's still not clear if you're working from a struct or what so the syntax will needs to change depending on that. Consider the above more pseudo code from that perspective.

Comment: Why not loop over the query instead of looping over the recordcount? A lot easier.

Comment: Almost, this does not quite answer my question, but it gives me an idea. I am getting the authorized_name variables from a form. Yes, it is quite unconventional because I am also using a plug-in to do ajax form submission. This plug-in requires I use a particular function to create a struct of the form inputs. The problem is the number of authorized_name fields is not known, so I must accomodate for any number. I must use the form IDs on the server side, I can't just create an array in js and pass it over.

Comment: @JeffFabiny, Check edits above and let me know if that's more what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JamesRLamar - Small comment about the example. If `numberAuthorized` represents a structure, you need to use `structCount`, or something similar. `Len()` does not work on complex objects, only strings. (And yes I checked it in Railo too ;-)

Comment: @Leigh, ha! Should have checked my work when I made the edit. Thanks!